# Notation to define a function mapping from a vector to a two-dimensional matrix

Tags: matrices, functions, notation

I have a set $\mathcal{D}$, and I'm trying to define a mapping from that set to a two-dimensional matrix where each location contains either a $1$ or $0$.

The notation I am using is  $\mathbf{P^{\omega}} : \mathcal{D} \to \{0, 1\}^{|R| \times |\
\mathcal{D}|}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: It is one of possible correct notations.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy is there a notation that is more intuitive or clearer than the one I am using? I am a software engineer and so my math notation is a bit rusty.

Comment: Hi! What is $R$?

Comment: @MattAllegro $R$ is another set that I have.

Comment: I'd use the notation $\mathcal D\to M_{|R|\times |\mathcal D|}(\{0,1\})$ to insist that we are talking about matrices ($M$) of certain dimensions ($|R|\times |\mathcal D|$) with elements in certain set ($\{0,1\}$).

Comment: Thank you @TZakrevskiy! That does look little more intuitive. If you post that as an answer, I can accept it. I'm assuming that $M$ is just a general notation for a matrix?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Agreed your last one, I think it's the standard (despite in this case is a bit heavy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per request, I post my comment as an answer:

I'd use the notation $\mathcal D\to M_{|R|\times |\mathcal D|}(\{0,1\})$ to insist that we are talking about matrices ($M$) of certain dimensions ($|R|\times |\mathcal D|$) with elements in a certain set ($\{0,1\}$).